# Pass multiple files based on wildcard in an array

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files (Datafile_1.txt,Datafile_2.txt and so on) and for each file I would like to perform some command.

This is what I have put together but it's not working as expected.

```
$FileName=$Datafile + "*.txt"
Files=@($FileName)
foreach ($File in $Files) 
{
Do something....
}
```

Could someone please share the right way to accomplish this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the “do something” that you are using the file names for?  Knowing that will help properly construct the names or actually find the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a string with an asterisk in it (and `Files` is missing a `$` but I imagine that's a typo).

You need to query the filesystem to get files matching the pattern and use them:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "DataFile*.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    Do-Something -With $_
}
```